# Vue component not loading in InertiaJS

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm using InertiaJS to build a Vue3 / Laravel app. When I run my app in the browser it gives me the following error in the console. I'm new to InertiaJS and Vue3 and don't know why my component doesn't render.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: l is null
```

web.php

```
// Home route. 
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])
```

HomeController.php

```
public function index()
{
    return Inertia::render('Home');
}
```

My app.blade.php file which is located under ./resources/views/app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>@yield('title') - Gainz</title>
        <meta 
        name="description" 
        content="@yield('description')">
        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="n5lVAknL3NblyWPmFzt3ARrtZbDDLIU-KOwA83NiO5w" />
        <!-- Roboto --> 
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;1,100;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <!-- CSS --> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">

        <!-- Bootstrap --> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Font Awesome --> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    
        <!-- Custom scripts --> 
        <script src="/js/app.js"></script>  
    </head>
    <body onmousedown="handleClick(event)">
        @inertia()
        @yield('scripts')
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const path = require('path')

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */
mix .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
    //.js('resources/js/track.js', 'public/js')
    //.js('resources/js/overview.js', 'public/js')
    //.js('resources/js/feed.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/main.scss', 'public/css');
// @ts-ignore
mix.webpackConfig({
    output: { chunkFilename: 'js/[name].js?id=[chunkhash]' },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': path.resolve('./resources/js'),
      },
      extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    },
    devServer: {
      allowedHosts: 'all',
    },
  });
```

app.js under ./resources/js/app.js

```
// @ts-nocheck
require('./bootstrap');
import { createApp, h } from 'vue'
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress'

// Creates the inertia vue app. 
createInertiaApp({
    resolve: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}`),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .mount(el);
    },
});
// Progress bar. 
InertiaProgress.init()
```

Finally Home.vue under ./resources/js/Pages/Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div>Hello world</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the defer attribute to the script tags of the app.js in app.blade.php seems to have solved the issue.

```
  <!-- Custom scripts --> 
        <script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Comment: Be helpful to some people to directly link to the "defer" documentation if possible or include why you think this solved your issue. Thanks for providing a solution :)

Comment: Indeed! I'm having the same issue with a template not rendering its content, but I already had the defer attribute.
My question is here if anyone has an answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70977245/new-laravel-vuejs-developer-missing-a-fundamental-bit-of-understanding?noredirect=1#comment125473603_70977245